# scala - cannot resolve symbol Map

Tags: scala, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I´m writing a simple code to test `CEP library` in Scala, maven dependency version **1.1-SNAPSHOT**. My code:

```
val res = igd.filter(_._2 == 13)
val pattern: Pattern[(Long,String,String,Long), _] = Pattern.begin[(Long,String,String,Long)]("start").where(_._3 == true).next("end").where(_._3 == false)
val patternStream: PatternStream[(Long,String,String,Long)] = CEP.pattern(res, pattern)

def selectFn(pattern : mutable.Map[String,(Long,String,String,Long)]): String = {
  val startEvent = pattern.get("start").get
  "Alerta:"+startEvent._1+": Pattern"
   }

val patternStreamSelected = patternStream.select(selectFn(_)).print
```

In `selecFn` the Map is in red with the message `cannot resolve symbol Map` 
Where is the problem?? Thank you in advance.

Comment: this sounds like an IDE problem, does the code compile?

Comment: No. Solved, I was importing  `scala.collection.parallel.mutable` instead of `scala.collection.mutable`. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, my..., i was importing `scala.collection.parallel.mutable` instead of `scala.collection.mutable`. Anyway, i think the scala lib still does not work, my little test didn´t do it, you can read [Simple Scala API for CEP example don't show any output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435302/simple-scala-api-for-cep-example-dont-show-any-output)